# How should generated code on Nuxt universal mode look like?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js

I have a more general question about nuxt, universal deployment mode and the code that comes as a result.

I have a nuxt application, deployed through npm run build and npm run start (universal mode) and when the CI/CD pipeline is finished and the code is successfully deployed, I go and see the code that is generated by nuxt.

As a reference, here is my link: view-source:https://staging.gemeentebanen.nl/

Is this how the source code is supposed to look in universal mode? Shouldn't I be able to see the HTML markup and stuff?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: yes, this is a rigth way.

Comment: thank you Henrique for your reply. However, doesn't this have any impact on the SEO? I mean...ok I can deal with head() through nuxt, but what about the html template?

Comment: take a look in your view-source:https://staging.gemeentebanen.nl... You have a head session in html format. See more detailed informations in this article, https://medium.com/vue-mastery/best-practices-for-nuxt-js-seo-32399c49b2e5